# When I update one table, it inserts the value of mapped table in hibernate mapping

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I have two models, `UserModel` and `RoleModel`, which are mapped with a `@OneToOne` relation. When I update the user details it first inserts data into the role table, then update those new role to `UserModel`.

**UserModel.java**

```java
package com.example.demo.Model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class UserModel {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name="name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name="address")
  private String address;
  @JoinColumn(name = "role", insertable=false, nullable = false, updatable = false)
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private RoleModel roleModel;

  public UserModel() {
  }

  public UserModel(Integer id, String name, String address,RoleModel roleModel) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.roleModel = roleModel;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public String getAddress() {
    return address;
  }
  public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
  }
  public RoleModel getRoleModel() {
    return roleModel;
  }
  public void setRoleModel(RoleModel roleModel) {
    this.roleModel = roleModel;
  }
}
```

**RoleModel.java**

```java
package com.example.demo.Model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Roles")
public class RoleModel {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="role")
  private Integer role;

  @Column(name="rolename")
  private String roleName;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "roleModel")
  private UserModel userModel;

  public RoleModel() {
  }

  public RoleModel(Integer role, String roleName) {
    super();
    this.role = role;
    this.roleName = roleName;
  }

  public Integer getRole() {
    return role;
  }
  public void setRole(Integer role) {
    this.role = role;
  }
  public String getRoleName() {
    return roleName;
  }
  public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
    this.roleName = roleName;
  }
}
```

I want to update `UserModel` along with role, but here `RoleModel` inserts a new row then it updates. Help me out regarding this. Tell me the exact code that I should use to only update the data from `UserModel` associated role.

Comment: Add the code where you create or modify the model and a clear explanation of what you expect to happen when you persist these modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend to research how spring relationship annotations work. You are making explicit that the `RoleModel` should not be neither inserted not updated when you are manipulating this object inside `UserModel`, so even if you modify the right information with the desired values it will not be reflected on the DB side.

```java
@JoinColumn(name = "role", insertable=false, nullable = false, updatable = false)
```

So, if you remove `insertable=false` and `updatable=false` from the mapping, it will work (considering the right column is mapped too).

Also, I recommend to research some tutorial about [Spring JPA One-to-One mappings](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one).

Answer (score 0):

Please change the `CascadeType` to `detach`, This work for me. Hope it help you.

```java
@JoinColumn(name = "role")

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)

private RoleModel roleModel;
```